# c++ getline file output change when is copied to string

Tags: c++

i have a file that each line of it have a row of matrix and in each row, double numbers placed with space between them, this file include a lot of these matrices with a empty line between them

now i have two different versions of code:

1- single thread read from file with getline(file, readLine) and directly process readLine, split it and use stod to make double numbers and make matrix

```
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void decomposeSerial(double *A, long n)
{
    long i, j, k;
    for (k = 0; k < n; k++) {
        for (j = k + 1; j < n; j++)
            A[k*n + j] = A[k*n + j] / A[k*n + k];

        for (i = k + 1; i < n; i++)
            for (j = k + 1; j < n; j++)
                A[i*n + j] = A[i*n + j] - A[i*n + k] * A[k*n + j];
    }
}

void main() {
    const string inFilePath = ".\\data_in\\file.txt";
    const string outFilePath = ".\\data_out\\file.txt";
    ifstream inFile(inFilePath);
    ofstream outFile(outFilePath);
    int n;
    int matrixLine = 0;
    double * matrix = NULL;
    string readLine;
    while (getline(inFile, readLine)) {
        if (!readLine.empty()) {
            if (matrixLine == 0) {
                n = 0;
                string temp = readLine;
                size_t pos = 0;
                while ((pos = temp.find(" ")) != string::npos) {
                    temp.erase(0, pos + 1);
                    n++;
                }
                matrix = (double *)malloc(sizeof(double) * n * n);
            }
            size_t pos = 0;
            string token;
            int i = 0;
            while ((pos = readLine.find(" ")) != string::npos) {
                token = readLine.substr(0, pos);
                matrix[matrixLine * n + i] = stod(token);
                readLine.erase(0, pos + 1);
                i++;
            }
            matrixLine++;
            if (matrixLine == n) {
                decomposeSerial(matrix, n);
                double det = 1;
                for (long o = 0; o < n; o++) {
                    det *= matrix[o * n + o];
                }
                outFile << det << "\n";
            }
        }
        else {
            matrixLine = 0;
        }
    }
    inFile.close();
    outFile.close();
}
```

http://codeshare.io/5enk9x

2- single thread read from file with getline(file, readLine) and append readLine to an element of a string array dedicated for this matrix, and after this, in parallel, each thread get one of these elements and go through the same process to make matrix

```
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <omp.h>

using namespace std;

double det[1000];
string input[1000];
int ns[1000];

void computation(double* src, int n, int l)
{
    long i, j, k;
    for (k = 0; k < n; k++) {
        for (j = k + 1; j < n; j++)
            src[k*n + j] = src[k*n + j] / src[k*n + k];

        for (i = k + 1; i < n; i++)
            for (j = k + 1; j < n; j++)
                src[i*n + j] = src[i*n + j] - src[i*n + k] * src[k*n + j];
    }
    double res = 1;
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        res *= src[j*n + j];
    }
    det[l] = res;
}

void main() {
    const string inFilePath = ".\\data_in\\file.txt";
    const string outFilePath = ".\\data_out\\file.txt";
    ifstream inFile(inFilePath);
    int matrixCount = 0;
    bool inMatrix = false;
    string readLine;
    int dim = 0;
    while (getline(inFile, readLine)) {
        dim++;
        if (readLine.empty()) {
            ns[matrixCount] = dim - 1;
            dim = 0;
            inMatrix = false;
            matrixCount++;
        }
        else {
            if (inMatrix == false) {
                inMatrix = true;
                input[matrixCount] = readLine;
            }
            else {
                input[matrixCount] += readLine;
            }
        }
    }
    ns[matrixCount] = dim;
    matrixCount++;
    inFile.close();
#pragma omp parallel
    {
#pragma omp for schedule(dynamic)
        for (int i = 0; i < matrixCount; i++) {
            string matrixStr = input[i];
            int n = ns[i];
            double * matrix = (double *)malloc(sizeof(double) * n * n);
            size_t pos = 0;
            string token;
            int k = 0;
            while ((pos = matrixStr.find(" ")) != string::npos) {
                token = matrixStr.substr(0, pos);
                matrix[k] = stod(token);
                matrixStr.erase(0, pos + 1);
                k++;
            }
            computation(matrix, n, i);

            free(matrix);
        }
    }
    ofstream outFile(outFilePath);
    for (int i = 0; i < matrixCount; i++) {
        outFile << det[i] << "\n";
    }
    outFile.close();
}
```

http://codeshare.io/ad83Yy

but incredibly, second code work much much slower to make matrices

when i print readLine what comes from getline func with printf("%s", readLine) it prints weird chars, anyway i got that when i append readLine to string array element, these weired chars change on the console and i guess that's why i get slower performance as functions line str.find(" ") or stod(str) work better with first weird ones comparing to second ones

if you think the same, you may suggest a way to prevent char changing in appending

Comment: Near impossible to answer without seeing at least some code.

Comment: Assumung `readLine` is a `std::string`, `printf("%s", readLine)` exhibits undefined behavior. First, `%s` specifier expects `char*` for a corresponding argument, and second, a non-POD class (such as `std::string`) cannot be passed to a variadic function (such as `printf`).

Comment: @IgorTandetnik sorry for bad c++ knowledge, i don't have that much exp in this lang, but i used printf to test, problem is somewhere else

Comment: I edited the question so that the code is visible directly without having to follow a link. In the future try to do that for the questions/answers you post.

Comment: Also, you say one version is much slower. How have you measured this? Please add that to the question.

Comment: @cigien ok tnx, if i won't finish my university project, at least i'll learn how to work with StackOverFlow :)

Comment: @cigien i don't see any need to add measurement, it's like simple 1000 times run and get end-start times of the code, with omp_get_wtime() and make avarage, but i can provide time differences for some number of matrices, i just saw the huge difference in run time and with print got the point that slow the work

Comment: You'll be glad to hear you don't need anyone's help to figure this out, just a tool you already have: your debugger! This is exactly what a debugger is for. It runs your program, one line at a time, and shows you what's happening. Knowing how to use a debugger is a required skill for every C++ developer, no exceptions. With your debugger's help you should be able to quickly find all bugs in this and all future programs you write, without having to ask anyone for help. Have you tried using your debugger, already? If not, why not? What did your debugger show you?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik tnx for reminding, the only difference that i can see in the flows is a jump to the xstring file line 86 in the parallel one at line `while ((pos = matrixStr.find(" ")) != string::npos) {`

Answer (score 0):

These kinds of performance issues can't be reasoned. You need to use a profiler and measure which parts of the code take up how much time.

To start with I would make both codes more similar. There are a lot of differences that could confuse the issue (for once version 1 has a giant memory leak).

Comment: the only huge difference is #pragma that could be commented, and it's still the same, about the memory leak, yeah i didn't know about the garbage collector of this lang, but as problem is opposite of this and i should fill a report considering these codes, i preferred not to change